# What does "credit" mean as a verb?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Kamala Harris](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/i-am-who-i-am-kamala-harris-daughter-of-indian-and-jamaican-immigrants-defines-herself-simply-as-american/2019/02/02/0b278536-24b7-11e9-ad53-824486280311_story.html?utm_term=.bf658eba6c13)

> She **credits** that largely to a Hindu immigrant single mom who adopted
>   black culture and immersed her daughters in it.

I looked up dictionary and there are 2 meanings as a verb:

> **V-T** When a sum of money is credited to an account, the bank adds that
>   sum of money to the total in the account.
>   **V-T** If people credit
>   someone with an achievement or if it is credited to them, people say
>   or believe that they were responsible for it.

It didn't seem fit.

Comment: From [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/credit) **credit** (verb) *1540s, "to believe, be sure of the truth of," from credit (n.). In a looser sense, "to attribute, give as the cause of," 1850. Meaning "to enter upon the credit side of an account" is from 1680s.* Is the "stretching" of meaning not reasonably comprehensible to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kamala Harris believes her mother is largely (mostly) responsible for her feeling comfortable with her identity from an early age. I will include the previous part of the paragraph, because it makes answering the question clearer.

> She calls herself simply “an American,” and said she has been fully
>   comfortable with her identity from an early age. She credits **that**
>   largely to a Hindu immigrant single mom who adopted black culture and
>   immersed her daughters in it.

1. The verb 'credit' here means 'to believe or say that somebody is responsible for doing something, especially something good'.
2. 'That' in the second sentence refers to 'something that has been mentioned or was involved earlier'. In this case, the thing 'that' refers to is in the earlier, previous sentence - Kamala Harris feeling comfortable with her identity from an early age (a good thing).

[Credit (verb)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/credit_2)

[That](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/that)

Comment: Oh, I see. "that" confused me most. "that" refers to the pervious sentence. I had thought "that" led a "that" clasue.